# Email and phone number validation javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make validation for my email input text and phone number input text. In the email, I want to put only '@gmail.com' and phone number the user only input number in the form. I already use JavaScript but it doesn't work.

```js
function validation() {
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@gmail.com*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  if (document.getElementById("name").value.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<em> You did not enter your name </em>";
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("email").value.match(mailformat) != mailformat) {
    document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = "<em> please enter </em>";
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("postcode").value.length < 4) {
    document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = "<em> Minimum is 4 Characters for Postcode </em>";
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("phone").value.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("message3").innerHTML = "<em> You did not enter your phone </em>";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal container" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="return validation()">
  <!-- Name Validation input -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2 label1" style="text-align: left;" for="name">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name">
      <span id="message"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Email Validation input -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 label1" style="text-align: left;" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
      <span id="message1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Postcode Validation Input -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 label1" style="text-align: left;" for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" class="form-control" id="postcode" placeholder="Enter Postcode" name="postcode">
      <span id="message2"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Phone Validation Input -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 label1" style="text-align: left;" for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" name="phone">
      <span id="message3"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit the query</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default button3"> Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where it shows error? Please explain

Comment: Add your form html as well?

Comment: `document.getElementById("email").value.match(mailformat) != mailformat ` that is not how you check if it passed.... Not sure where you learned that from.

Comment: I put this code but when I type the wrong email. The code is not showing notification like "please enter email contain @gmail" and also when I put wrong value in the phone number like "P1234" in the input text, it doesn't error notification that i put wrong value

Comment: @epascarello I'm new with javascript. So, that's why I need to discuss about it in the StackOverflow.

Comment: @Asif i already put my html code

Comment: @MarkReed I just want to make a specific email in the form. So, the user can input email only gmail.com but I don't know how to do it and i try to experiment but it's fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex like this

`var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*[@gmail.com]*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
var email_val = document.getElementById("email").value;
if(!email_val.match(mailformat)){
   document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = "<em> please enter email dsfsdfa</em>";
   return false;
}`

You can make it more better, like apply validation for empty field before this too.

Comment: Updated, Please check again

Comment: can i use same logic in the phone validation @Asif

Comment: Yes you can try, let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Match returns an array if it is matched. So comparing an array to a regular expression is wrong. You can use a truthy check

```
if(!document.getElementById("email").value.match(mailformat)) {
```

or use [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead.

Comment: my guess it is the reg exp.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this website which shows basic javascript code for validation

https://getcodingkids.com/mission/mission-2/

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get your email validation regex? The pattern `/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@gmail.com*(\.\w{2,3})+$/` matches (inefficiently) one or more words joined by periods or hyphens, followed by `@gmail`,followed by any character at all, followed by `co`, followed by any number of `m`s including zero, followed by at least one sequence of period plus two or three more letters. So it won't match anything ending in `@gmail.com`, but will match something ending in `@gmail.co.uk` or similar. So even if you fix the validation logic in the code, this regex won't match against any email address ending in `gmail.com`, which it sounds like you want to do..

Comment: I just want to make a specific email in the form. So, the user can input email only gmail.com but I don't know how to do it and i try to experiment but it's fail